# Can I configure wildfly servers on myeclipse 10?

Tags: wildfly, myeclipse

Although myeclipse 10 is an old IDE from 2010, I have a bunch of old eclipse IDEs like this one on my disk. Since Wildfly servers were not made at that time, the program's Preferences window only shows options to configure jboss 2.x - 7.x servers.

Which myeclipse releases can configure a Wildfly 11 server? (and I haven't downloaded the server yet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That release is no longer supported but you could try configuring it as the latest JBoss release there (7.x). It might work, though this hasn't been tested. Alternatively, there should be an option to configure an externally launched server (i.e. you'd have to launch it outside of MyEclipse) which allows you to specify a deployment location so that it can be deployed from MyEclipse. Sorry, I don't have that release immediately to hand to check the details but it may be in the product in-line help. Hope this helps.